# SOAP call fails when deployed on websphere but works fine on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, websphere

I have a spring boot soap client that works fine when I run it on tomcat but when I deploy the same client on websphere, the SOAP call fails with the following message. It complaining that the

> SOAPHeaderElement that was not namespace qualified. The SOAPHeaderElement localName is clientVersion; prefix is null: namespace is null.'

```
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
    try {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
        SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        StringSource headerSource = new StringSource(
                "<clientVersion>" + clientVersionNumber + "</clientVersion>");
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

[24/02/20 15:06:56:239 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R FATAL ERROR:  'java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: WSWS4119E: An attempt was made to set a SOAPHeaderElement that was not namespace qualified. The SOAPHeaderElement localName is clientVersion; prefix is null: namespace is null.'
           :javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: WSWS4119E: An attempt was made to set a SOAPHeaderElement that was not namespace qualified. The SOAPHeaderElement localName is clientVersion; prefix is null: namespace is null.
[24/02/20 15:06:56:342 EST] 000000c6 AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive An error was detected during JAXWS processing
                                 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: An error was detected during JAXWS processing
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1633)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

[24/02/20 15:06:56:376 EST] 000000c7 SystemOut     O Excpetion caught: null
[24/02/20 15:06:56:361 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Internal Error
[24/02/20 15:06:56:361 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:361 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:361 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at client.tphehtvc.service.SoapClient.callRemoteService(SoapClient.java:89)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at client.tphehtvc.service.SoapClient.getScheduledWorkHH(SoapClient.java:142)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at client.tphehtvc.controller.ScheduleWork.getScheduledWorkHH(ScheduleWork.java:416)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:362 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:363 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:364 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:365 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:366 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:367 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:368 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:369 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:370 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:371 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:371 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:371 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:372 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:372 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:372 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:372 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4219)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:373 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:373 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:373 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:373 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:374 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:374 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:374 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:374 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[24/02/20 15:06:56:375 EST] 000000c7 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

Can someone show me how I can correctly set the `SOAPHeaderElement`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two solutions to this issue.

1. Change the classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST" for the web module.
2. Use a SoapHeaderElement instead of StringSource

   ```
   public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
     try {
       SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
       SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
       SoapHeaderElement messageId =  header.addHeaderElement(
               new QName("http://<namespace>", "clientVersion", ""));
       messageId.setText(clientVersionNumber);

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've never attempted this myself, but first things first. The WebServiceMessage object looks like it is a part of the Spring's Web Services implementation. If you plan on using any other Web Service implementation other than the one that comes with WebSphere, you'll need to disable it. You can find out how to do that here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

That alone might fix you're issue, but if you want to use WebSphere's JAX-WS implementation then remove the references to Spring Web Services API's, and follow the documentation on how to create a SOAPHeaderElement using a handler in the WebSphere Knowledge Center:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8JB4/com.ibm.wbpm.wid.integ.doc/webservice/topics/rsoapheaderjaxws.html